# How to configure Ember Routing for list/single item templates?

Tags: ember.js

I want to have a list of items in a table at the top of a page.  When a user clicks on one of the items in the table, the item should render in a  below the table.  Here is what my list of things HBS looks like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="things">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>My Things</h1>
    </div>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>prop1</th>
        <th>pro2</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        {{#each thing controller}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{#linkTo "thing" thing}}{{ thing.prop1 }}{{/linkTo}}</td>
            <td>{{ thing.prop2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ thing.prop3 }}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
    </div>
    <div>
    {{render "thing"}}
    </div>
</script>
```

If I use the linkTo, I get the error:

> You can only use the {{render}} helper once without a model object as
>   its second argument, as in {{render "post" post}}.

Interestingly enough, I can navigate the the URL (ie ../#/things/1) and it renders fine.  Here is my routing map:

```
App.Router.map(function(){ //map URLs to templates
   this.resource('things', function(){
       this.resource('thing', {path: ':thing_id'});
   }); //maps to /#/contacts
    //define all other URLs in application
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  The `{{render "thing"}}` in the HBS should be replaced with `{{outlet}}`, as such:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="things">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>My Things</h1>
    </div>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>prop1</th>
        <th>pro2</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        {{#each thing controller}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{#linkTo "thing" thing}}{{ thing.prop1 }}{{/linkTo}}</td>
            <td>{{ thing.prop2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ thing.prop3 }}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
    </div>
    <div>
    {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your things controller extending array controller?

```
 App.ThingsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

 })
```

do your properties render?

```
 {{#each item in controller}}
  {{item.prop}}
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: linkTo was deprecated, link-to is preferred as well, but I think linkTo still works just fine.